# What is the super fast and prefered way for two code bellow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, socket.io

My code get all online people from server
But I just need just those online people that I have in my contact list.

there I have two way:

1. having two `nested loop` to comare all online people with those online people I have in my conact list and then just add online people of my contact list to an `Object` in my **App**. code is below:

```
people = {};
myContacts = [...];
this.socket.on('online', users => {
    for (let i = users.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
         for (let j = myContacts.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
             if (myContacts[j].userid === users[i]) {
                this.people[myContacts[j].userid] = 'online';
             }
        }
    }
   this.setState({refresh: !this.state.refresh});
});
```

2. having just one loop and adding all online people to an object in my **App**. code is below:

```
people = {};
myContacts = [...];
this.socket.on('online', users => {
    for (let i = users.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
         this.people[users[i]] = 'online';
    }
   this.setState({refresh: !this.state.refresh});
});
```

Now my question is: What is best way which of the above number you prefer me for having a good performance and a fast job during using the **App**.

**Note: Why I am worry about this although both of them works well, you think there is 10000 people online at the same time.

Here may you tell me second one is better because there is one loop,
but I am confusing if we have 10000 people online on that time we will have 10000 people in the Object and accessing online people we need from the object by username may take a long time.
But in first code getting people take much time because we have two loop and comparing them but accessing within the app will be easy because we just have those online people are in my contact list.**

Comment: i tink the second one is better, your runtime is faster

Comment: @NoobDEV-GBL please read the note part I have edited

Comment: ya you are right, sorry,  on that case the run time of the first will be faster then the second one, becouse you are adding just the online that are not on contact list, in the other case you will always add all of the online...so that makes the second lots or time to run

Comment: A little bit of advice, don't try an pre-optimise Javascript.  It often performs better in areas you would not expect,.   For example, it might seem logical that a `map`, due to hash table lookup performance would always be faster than a `Array.find`.   But that's not always the case.  It normally a much better idea to get your code working, and then optimise if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO browser's native `includes()` (applied to bigger array) method should be the fastest one:

```
for (let j = myContacts.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
  this.people[myContacts[j].userid] = users.includes( myContacts[j].userid ) ? 'online' : 'offline';
}
```

you can also store only a boolean value

```
for (let j = myContacts.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
  this.people[myContacts[j].userid] = users.includes( myContacts[j].userid );
}
```

and render conditionally what you need (translated message, icon, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to only show online people who are in your contact list, I think you can turn myContacts array into a key/value object {...}. Key is userID and value is boolean (true: online, false: offline). That would help to speed up performance a bit